# Custom Binding with a List of a Custom Class request string is invalid

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, custom-binding

I am having some troubles with my MVC application

I have created custom binders and they are working for everything except my list of QueryTags

```
    public class QueryTag
{
    [Key]
    public int QueryTagId { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

In my Binder

```
            string tagName;
            int index = 0;
            List<QueryTag> tagList = new List<QueryTag>();

            while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tagName = request.Form["QueryTags[" + (index++) + "].TagName"]))
            {
                tagList.Add(new QueryTag()
                {
                    QueryTagId = int.Parse(request["QueryTags[" + (index) + "].QueryTagId"]),
                    TagName = tagName,
                    IsChecked = request["QueryTags[" + (index) + "].IsChecked"] == "ture,false"
                });
            }

            if (tagList.Count == 0)
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("QueryTags[0]", "Something went wrong with the query tags");
            }
            else
            {
                model.QueryTags = tagList;
            }
```

and I am using a view with a jquery popup modal like so:

> ```
>         <input type="button" value="Add Tags" id="QueryTagOpener" />
>         <div id="QueryTagPopup" title="Query Tags">
>             <div style="width: 25%; float: left">
>                 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.QueryTags.Count(); ++i)
>                 {
>                     <div class="editor-field">
>                         @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.QueryTags[i].TagName)
>                     </div>
>                     <div>
>                         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QueryTags[i].IsChecked)
>                     </div>
>                 }
>             </div>
>         </div>
> ```

The request.Form["QueryTags[" + (index++) + "].TagName"] is always null.

I am assuming it has something to do with the jquery popup but I have tried implementing the view like I am for other properties that work with no luck.

I am sure it is something simple but have been bouncing around the internet for hours banging my head and can't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As it stands, you'd be starting out the `QueryTags` with an index of 1; I'm not 100% sure, but I seem to remember MVC throwing fits if you didn't hand it back sequential 0-based indices.

Comment: I am using the exact same syntax in my binder for a different property that is also a list. It works and starts from 0. :s